# In werewolv.es, how does the succubus interact with other coven roles with dual abilities?

Tags: werewolv.es

In werewolv.es, some roles like the the Shaman, Harpy, Witch and Alchemist have multiple abilities.

If a succubus was used to redirect these abilities, which ability will be redirected for each of Shaman, Harpy, Witch, and Alchemist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a role has a primary and secondary ability, any Succubus redirects will affect the primary ability of the target and the secondary ability will work as normal. Since the Succubus may target friendly Coven players, their abilities are listed here.

```
Role         | Primary Ability   | Secondary Ability
-----------------------------------------------------
Alchemist    | Transmute         | Purge
Harpy        | Shroud            | Silence
Shaman       | Protect           | Lure
Witch        | Kill              | Revive
            <<<  werewolf roles >>>
Alphawolf    | Wolf Kill         | Enraged Kill
Shapeshifter | Wolf Kill         | Shapeshift
Omegawolf*   | Massacre          | Guard
            <<<  undead roles   >>>
Necromancer**| Dead target revive| Living target
```

*The Omegawolf has night immunity so cannot be redirected, but is included in the table for completeness
** Edited to include the Primary and Secondary Abilities of the Necromancer from the Undead faction

Comment: To further add to this answer, as the Undead faction has been omitted from the table:

With regards to the Necromancer, their Primary Ability is considered to be targeting the DEAD player in the graveyard for the Revive ability, and the Secondary Ability is targeting the living player that Graveyard target will become.

Therefore the Succubus must redirect the Necromancer to another DEAD player in the Graveyard of their choice, and not redirect to an ALIVE player.