# Interaction Succubus - Undead roles

Tags: werewolv.es

Question: how does the Succubus interact with the Necromancer and the Banshee?

This question consists of two subquestions:

- Which ability of the Necromancer does the Succubus redirect; i.e can they redirect the person that is revived or the person that is being swapped into?
- Can a Succubus redirect the Banshee once they're in the Graveyard? (general question is whether Succubus can redirect dead players, but this seems only relevant for the Banshee)

(I saw the overview of Succubus interactions with Wolfpack and Coven in [In werewolv.es, how does the succubus interact with other coven roles with dual abilities?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/351353/in-werewolv-es-how-does-the-succubus-interact-with-other-coven-roles-with-dual), this question serves to give the overview for relevant Undead roles)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Succubus can only redirect the primary ability of a player, and in the Necromancer's case, the primary ability (or visit) is considered to be the dead player they visit.

The Succubus can only target living players, so they would not be able to redirect a Banshee.